# js works in ios 10 but not 9?

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm coding a page that uses js for accordions and tab switching, but it's not displaying on ios 9? It's works fine on desktop and on my ipad which uses ios 10. Media queries working fine?!? Please help!

This is my script:

```js
<script>    
    $(document).ready(() => {
 
        $('[data-accordion]').each((i, val) => {
            const acc = $(val);
            const id = acc.data('accordion');

            acc.append('<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-icon></span>');

            acc.on('click', () => {
                const el = $(`#${id}`);
                el.toggle();
                acc.find('[data-icon]').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus');
            });
        });

        $('[data-page]').each((i, val) => {
            const page = $(val);
            const id = page.data('page');

            page.on('click', () => {
                const el = $(`#${id}`);
                $('.activeb[data-page]').each((i, val) => {
                    const activebPage = $(val);
                    const activebId = activebPage.data('page');
                    const activebElement = $(`#${activebId}`);
                    activebPage.removeClass('activeb');
                    activebElement.hide();
                });
                el.show();

                page.addClass('activeb');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have cursor: pointer; but nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using iOS 9 Safari or Chrome. iOS 9 Safari/Chrome [don't support arrow functions](http://caniuse.com/#search=arrow). iOS 10 Safari/Chrome do.

None of your arrow functions need to be arrow functions, so to support earlier versions of iOS, just replace them with `function` functions. E.g., replace

```
$(document).ready(() => {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

...and so on.

Comment: @josie: Well, you're also using template literals, which IE11 *also* doesn't support.